# Mysql join for more than one column of Table A with another table B

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a solution for the same by joining the same table twice but I am wondering if the below query can be optimized?

```
select oc.name as father_occupation, o.name as mother_occupation 
from user_family uf 
left join occupations oc on uf.father_occupation = oc.occupation_id
left join occupations o on uf.mother_occupation = o.occupation_id
where user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Hm, I think I have issues with the rest of your implied table design.  If, though, you're trying to simplify a larger query, please post the _entire_ thing here, and hopefully table layouts/sample data and desired results too.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse it's just like a simple mapping structure where occupation names are stored against ids in 'occupations' table and i have to select father and mother's occupation from family table which contains the id which map to 'occupation' table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check two conditions in one left join

```
   select oc.name as father_occupation, o.name as mother_occupation 
    from user_family uf 
    left join occupations oc on uf.father_occupation = oc.occupation_id and uf.mother_occupation = oc.occupation_id where user_id = 1;
```

Comment: @Him  have you checked my coding?

Comment: Yes, that works with a minor change 'oc.name' instead of 'o.name' but If I have more than two columns then i need to do 'AND' of all the columns? Any other better way to do so? Actually I am looking for the alternative of 'IN' for inner query. I hope that explains my intent.

Comment: @Him definitely if you want check more column you should use 'And' condition in my point of view.. 'IN' is used for the same column with multiple values checking..

Comment: Uh, no, this doesn't work; it presumes that both the mother and father have the same occupation (and that both parents actually have one), which is generally unlikely.